# Peoplepicker with ADFS login

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, people-picker, adfs, claim-provider

We are using `ADFS` for authentication. I have a people & groups in my custom list which accepts the users and groups. Currently I'm able to give the group names, but its not taking any user names. Its working, if I give the email address of the user. How can we add the user name in `ADFS` to the people picker instead of email address ?

Answer (score 0):

While configuring ADFS you have to setup the username claim type aswell.  So that people picker can search against username.